# Finding the target of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-controls

I've been looking for the answer for quite a while, but haven't found a complete solution. I'm not sure if I searched with the good terms. So here it is : I want to target elements and change their text. Right now I use one function per element, but it's pretty repetitive, so here is an example :

HTML

```
<p id="p1" onClick="change1()">Hello</p>
<p id="p2" onClick="change2()">My name is Ben</p>
<p id="p3" onClick="change2()">Good Bye</p>
```

JavaScript

```
function change1() {
    var test = prompt('Enter new text here');
    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = test;
}
function change2() {
    var test = prompt('Enter new text here');
    document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = test;
}
function change3() {
    var test = prompt('Enter new text here');
    document.getElementById('p3').innerHTML = test;
}
```

So what I'm doing is allowing the user to change the text in a "p" element. But as you may see, things can get lengthy if I need to repeat the functions for a hundred elements on the page. Is there a way to use `event.target` or something else to find the "id" of the "p" element that was clicked and then put in the value of the prompt box? I'd just like a generic function that would prevent all these repetitions.

A bonus would be to not use "onclick" at each element (something like $('p').click...) that would be applicable to all p elements.

I'd prefer JavaScript without JQuery, but if it's much simpler, I'll use it.

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within an `onclick` attribute, `this` is the target. You can then pass it as an argument to the function.

```js
function change(element) {
  var test = prompt('Enter new text here');
  element.innerHTML = test;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1" onClick="change(this)">Hello</p>
<p id="p2" onClick="change(this)">My name is Ben</p>
<p id="p3" onClick="change(this)">Good Bye</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you will make much less effort if you use jquery. Take a look at this:

```
$('[id=^p]').on('click', function(obj) {
    var test = prompt('Enter new text here');
    var n = test.length;
    if(n > 0) 
       obj.html(test);
});
```

Without it you would have to use a getElementByTag and iterate through a for. You can do that, but jquery really saves some time here.

With this solution you also have the advantage that you don't need no code in your html which allows for better separation between view and business layers.